# i want to print artist name as a array from mp3 file using php

Tags: php

i have string line in php , and this line is

**" hello , my , name , ajay , and , i , am , vegetarian "**

I want to php script that store automatically all word after comma(,) in a new variable. I don`t know  how to do that. please help me.

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with your text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "hello , my , name , ajay , and , i , am , vegetarian";

$Ary = explode(",", $str);

foreach($Ary as $row) {
    $data[] = trim($row);
}
print_r($data);
extract($data);
```

Comment: i want to store all array value in 10 different variable like a1 = hello ,a2 = my,....a8 = vejetarian and a9 = 0 , a10 = 0 . .. I want to that if no value for 'a9' and 'a10' then thats value is '0'.